# Sending notifications from irssi to wmii

Tags: bash, irssi

So this is two questions in one.

Simply setting `PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]2;BLAH\007"` will change an xterm titlebar to the string "BLAH", even under wmii. Of course, I can also change the command to write directly, using `echo "BLAH" | wmiir write /clients/sel/label` to achieve the same result.

However it's not clear to me of it's possible to change the color scheme (i.e., wmiir xwrite /some/path/ctl WMII_COLORS) to a specific out-of-focus tiled client under WMII. If anyone has a patch to do be able to do this, I'd be grateful. Worse comes to worse, it's easy enough to trigger the menubar to 'flash', or the tag in question, using the wmiir write method on /lbar or /rbar.

On the other hand, is there a way to generate a specific event that wmii or the calling shell can recognize while using `irssi`? If I can't change colors, simply changing the title via the shell variable would be enough. I'd also be happy with any method of triggering a local script on irc events, like receiving a private message or someone in-channel using my nick.

My goal is to make the window/client/tile in question simply "flash" a different color when receiving new messages. As I'm running this all on a BSD inside a VM (FreeBSD 10.2 on a Parallels image running under Mac OS X, access via VNC) the usual notification schema aren't available.

Answer (score 1):

Terminal titlebars don't blink or have colors.  It's not a feature that you can get using escape sequences.  The appearance of the titlebar is controlled by the window manager.

Conceivably, a window manager *could* be written to make a blinking title. However, it's not a documented feature of `wmii`.

Further reading:

- [wmii](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wmii) (Arch wiki)
- [The wmii Window Manager](http://paulgorman.org/technical/wmii.php)